# Store POJO as JSON in Java MongoDB

Tags: java, json, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

**PROBLEM** One of the enclosed POJO's (data) is persisted with types, but I expect it to be persisted with plain JSON.

[image: MongoDB JSON]

**RESEARCH** My MongoConfiguration class:

```
  @Configuration
  @EnableMongoRepositories
  //@EnableJpaRepositories
  public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {
  
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
    public String connectionString;
  
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String database;
  
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.username}")
    private String userName;
  
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.password}")
    private char[] password;
  
    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
      return "my";
    }
  
    @Override
    protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
      return "com.example.context";
    }
  
    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
  
      MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(MongoClientSettings.builder()
          .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(connectionString))
          .uuidRepresentation(UuidRepresentation.STANDARD)
          .credential(MongoCredential.createCredential(
              userName, database, password))
          .build());
  
      SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory mongoDatabaseFactory =
          new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(mongoClient, database);
  
      MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(
          mongoDatabaseFactory, getMongoConverter(mongoDatabaseFactory));
  
  //    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, database);
  
      return mongoTemplate;
    }
  
    private MappingMongoConverter getMongoConverter(MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDatabaseFactory) {
      MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(
          new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDatabaseFactory),
          new MongoMappingContext());
  
      converter.setCustomConversions(customConversions());
      converter.afterPropertiesSet();
      return converter;
    }
  
    @Override
    public MongoCustomConversions customConversions() {
      List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
      converters.add(new ZonedDateTimeReadConverter());
      converters.add(new ZonedDateTimeWriteConverter());
      converters.add(new UuidReadConverter());
      converters.add(new UuidWriteConverter());
      return new MongoCustomConversions(converters);
    }
  
    @ReadingConverter
    public static class ZonedDateTimeReadConverter implements Converter<Date, ZonedDateTime> {
  
      @Override
      public ZonedDateTime convert(Date date) {
        return date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
      }
    }
  
    @WritingConverter
    public static class ZonedDateTimeWriteConverter implements Converter<ZonedDateTime, Date> {
  
      @Override
      public Date convert(ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime) {
        return Date.from(zonedDateTime.toInstant());
      }
    }
  
    @ReadingConverter
    public static class UuidReadConverter implements Converter<Binary, UUID> {
  
      @Override
      public UUID convert(Binary binary) {
        long msb = 0;
        long lsb = 0;
        byte[] uuidBytes = binary.getData();
  
        for (int i = 8; i < 16; i++) {
          lsb <<= 8;
          lsb |= uuidBytes[i] & 0xFFL;
        }
  
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
          msb <<= 8;
          msb |= uuidBytes[i] & 0xFFL;
        }
  
        return new UUID(msb, lsb);
      }
    }
  
    @WritingConverter
    public static class UuidWriteConverter implements Converter<UUID, Binary> {
  
      @Override
      public Binary convert(UUID uuid) {
        long msb = uuid.getMostSignificantBits();
        long lsb = uuid.getLeastSignificantBits();
  
        byte[] uuidBytes = new byte[16];
  
        for (int i = 15; i >= 8; i--) {
          uuidBytes[i] = (byte) (lsb & 0xFFL);
          lsb >>= 8;
        }
  
        for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
          uuidBytes[i] = (byte) (msb & 0xFFL);
          msb >>= 8;
        }
  
        return new Binary((byte) 0x04, uuidBytes);
      }
    }
  }
```

Spring Data Repository:

```
@Repository
  public interface EventRepositoryImpl extends MongoRepository<DomainEvent, UUID>,
      PagingAndSortingRepository<DomainEvent, UUID>,
      EventRepository {
  
    @Override
    default DomainEvent persist(DomainEvent event) {
      DomainEvent savedEvent = save(event);
      return savedEvent;
    }
 }
```

Persisted record model:

```
@Builder
@Getter
public class DomainEventImpl implements DomainEvent {

  private UUID id;
  private ZonedDateTime createdAt;
  private DomainAggregate data;
  private long modelVersion;
}
```

QUESTION How to persist data embedded object so that it looks like classic JSON in Mongo Database?

Comment: Spring data maps data types to mongo.  This is preferred.  MongoDB will operate faster and more efficiently with proper datatypes.  Having said that, if you want to remove all datatype options, simply use String datatypes in your POJO.  All the datatypes in Mongo will be string, which is the same as JSON.

Comment: BTW - Mongo does not store JSON.  It stores BSON.  The data layer is converting your regular data to binary types on disk.  Again, for performance reasons...

Comment: Also, you can store the data in proper datatypes, but convert them to string on output of a query using aggregation framework and projections...

Comment: _"data embedded object"_: Which embedded object?